# Change HTML select option values depending on another select option value

Tags: jquery, html, forms

here's my code:

```
<form>
 <select name="choose">
  <option value="0">a</option>
  <option value="1">b</option>
 </select>

 <select name="choose2">
  <option value="7">x</option>
  <option value="8">y</option>
  <option value="9">z</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Now I want to change the option values of the select "choose2" depending on the option value that clicked in "choose" e.g.: if you choose b in the first choose, the values in choose2 would change to 10, 11, 12 and j, k, l. Does anyone got a good solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried something ? Can we have what you tried ?

Comment: From where you are populating the data?

Comment: I have tried several solutions from here but none worked. I tried it with Javascript and jQuery.

Comment: What is your JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you can this with jquery;

```
function changer(eq, val, text) {
    $('select[name="choose2"] option:nth-child('+eq+')').val(val).text(text);
}

$('select[name="choose"]').change(function(){
    changer(1, '10', 'j');
    changer(2, '11', 'k');
    changer(3, '12', 'l');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bqra/guwzynz1/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in jQuery:

```
$('select#id_of_first_select').on('change',function(){

   if ($(this).val() == 'b'){
      $('select#id_of_sec_select option').each(function(i){
         $(this).val('asdf'); //use array if you want different values
         $(this).attr('value','1234');
      });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#main').change(function(){
  var sel = $(this),
      val = sel.val(),
      second = $('#second');
  
  var options = ['opt_1_' + val, 'opt_2_' + val, 'opt_3_' + val];
  
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      html += '<option>' + options[i] + '</option>';
  }
  
  second.html(html);
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="main">
  <option value="1">Option1</option>
  <option value="2">Option2</option>
  <option value="3">Option3</option>
</select>

<select id="second">
  
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put in all options. like this.

```
<form>
 <select name="choose">
  <option value="0">a</option>
  <option value="1">b</option>
 </select>

 <select name="choose2">
  <option class="optiona" value="7">x</option>
  <option class="optiona" value="8">y</option>
  <option class="optiona" value="9">z</option>
  <option class="optionb" value="10" hidden>j</option>
  <option class="optionb" value="11" hidden>k</option>
  <option class="optionb" value="12" hidden>l</option>
 </select>
</form>



$(document).ready(function(){
$('select[name="choose"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).attr("value")=="0"){
        $(".optiona").show();
        $(".optionb").hide();

    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="1"){
        $(".optiona").hide();
        $(".optionb").show();
    }
});
});
```